# Using multer when I upload an image it shows me a message that image has been successfully added but does not added to upload folder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

> Here's my code to upload and save image in database , when I do this
> on postman it gives an error of 'undefined' but 'file uploaded
> successfully' and neither did my image/file is stored in upload folder

//multerfile

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'originalname');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
});
const filefilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' 
        || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'){
            cb(null, true);
        }else {
            cb(null, false);
        }
}

const upload = multer({storage: storage, fileFilter: filefilter});

module.exports = {upload}
```

//imagedata model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');


const imageSchema=new  mongoose.Schema({

    fileName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    filePath: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fileType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    fileSize: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports=mongoose.model('imagedata', imageSchema);
```

//post controller

```
exports.uploadimage = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{

        const file= req.file;
        console.log(file);
        res.status(201).json({messsage:"file uploaded successfully"})

    }catch(error){

        res.status(400).send(error.message)
    }
```

Comment: u have not specified the destination where u want to save the file 

destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u have not specified the destination where u want to save the file
create a folder named uploads in ur project and make changes as I have mentioned below:

```
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'uploads/originalname');
   },
```

Comment: what are u using to upload the file is it postman or some frontend framework, if u are using a frontend framework u can check the headers whether a file is being sent or not, in short debug the code whether u are sending the file properly or not.